# List in List Model ASP Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model

How to properly put the `List` in the model with the assignment of values ​​from the model - to form `JsonResult` in `MasterDetail`

The value of "Test2" is accepted normally, but with the assignment of the problem, the field initializer can not access the non-static field, method, or "List1" property.

```
public class List1 {

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string SecondName { get; set; }

   public string Login { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public List<Test> Test { get; set; } = new List<Test>
   {
       new Test() { Name = Login, Age = "Age1" },  
       new Test() { Name = "Test2", Age = "Age2" }            
   };
}

public  class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As it states in error "the field initializer can not access the **non-static** field, method, or "List1" property.". `Login` property is not known during initialization. Even more, it would be always **null** when the Test is init. How do you instantiate the List1 class?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to put an uninstantiated object into a string variable, here:

```
new Test() { Name = Login, Age = "Age1" },
```

To make your code work, you first have to have a filled Login object, after which you could put its value in the list using:

```
List1 l1 = new List1{ Login = "ABCD" }
new Test() { Name = l1.Login, Age = "Age1" },
```

Comment: Yes, but data in the `Login` field I get from the database - so i need `get;set;`

Comment: The model class only contains pointers as to where the data from the database will be put.
At compile time, which is when you want to execute this function, you cannot put the reference into an object, since it contains nothing.

To achieve what you want to do, you have to first populate the model from the database, then access it and populate the desired field.
As Krypt1 asked above: How do you instantiate the List1 class?